# lua script and when executed via wrk the version is different

Tags: lua, wrk

I have a lua script test.lua
which when executed `lua test.lua` it executes and provides me output as expected and it uses lua 5.3 when compiling

But when i execute the same test.lua via wrk (http performance test benchmark  brew tool) , it reached to lua 5.1 (which I dont have in my system) rather than 5.3

And there is no any wrk config which tries to reach to lua 5.1 . I am not sure why it behaves different and hits different version of lua

An hint to this confusion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the LuaJIT site, [here](http://luajit.org/install.html):

> LuaJIT is API-compatible with Lua 5.1

wrk uses LuaJIT, as noted [here](https://github.com/wg/wrk).